# Printer Only Print One Page

Tags: macos, networking, printer, network-printer

I have a printer [Canon LBP6230dn](http://www.canon.com.my/personal/products/laser-printers/laser-single-function/imageclass-lbp6230dn) and I am on Mac OS X 10.10 (Yosemite). My printer is on the network. Other computer with same specs and OS is fine. I can print 12 pages with duplex okay but if there are many pages printer is only printing first page many times.

I happened to install an old driver, may be it is cached?

> print duplex command -> printer one page -> stop and ask for paper
>   feed -> print the same page again

My computer specifications

- Mac Book Pro 2012 (13")
- RAM 16G
- 256 SSD
- Mac OS X 10.10 (Yosemite)
- LBP 6230dn connect with network cable.